# How to configure hibernate-tools with maven to generate hibernate.cfg.xml, *.hbm.xml, POJOs and DAOs

Tags: hibernate, maven-2, hibernate-tools

can any one tell me how to force maven to precede mapping .hbm.xml files in the automatically generated hibernate.cfg.xml file with package path?

My general idea is, I'd like to use hibernate-tools via maven to generate the persistence layer for my application. So, I need the hibernate.cfg.xml, then all my_table_names.hbm.xml and at the end the POJO's generated. Yet, the `hbm2java` goal won't work as I put *.hbm.xml files into the `src/main/resources/package/path/` folder but `hbm2cfgxml` specifies the mapping files only by table name, i.e.:

```
<mapping resource="MyTableName.hbm.xml" />
```

So the big question is: how can I configure `hbm2cfgxml` so that hibernate.cfg.xml looks like below:

```
<mapping resource="package/path/MyTableName.hbm.xml" />
```

My pom.xml looks like this at the moment:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>hbm2cfgxml</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>hbm2cfgxml</goal>
            </goals>
            <inherited>false</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <components>
                    <component>
                        <name>hbm2cfgxml</name>
                        <implemetation>jdbcconfiguration</implementation>
                        <outputDirectory>src/main/resources/</outputDirectory>
                    </component>
                </components>
                <componentProperties>
                    <packagename>package.path</packageName>
                    <configurationFile>src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml</configurationFile>
                </componentProperties>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And then the second question: is there a way to tell maven to copy resources to the target folder before executing `hbm2java`? At the moment I'm using

```
mvn clean resources:resources generate-sources
```

for that, but there must be a better way.

Thanks for any help.

**Update:**

**@Pascal:** Thank you for your help. The path to mappings works fine now, I don't know what was wrong before, though. Maybe there is some issue with writing to hibernate.cfg.xml while reading database config from it (though the file gets updated).

I've deleted the file hibernate.cfg.xml, replaced it with database.properties and run the goals `hbm2cfgxml` and `hbm2hbmxml`. I also don't use the `outputDirectory` nor `configurationfile` in those goals anymore.

As a result the files `hibernate.cfg.xml` and all `*.hbm.xml` are being generated into my target/hibernate3/generated-mappings/ folder, which is the default value. Then I updated the `hbm2java` goal with the following:

```
<componentProperties>
    <packagename>package.name</packagename>
    <configurationfile>target/hibernate3/generated-mappings/hibernate.cfg.xml</configurationfile>
</componentProperties>
```

But then I get the following:

```
[INFO] --- hibernate3-maven-plugin:2.2:hbm2java (hbm2java) @ project.persistence ---
[INFO] using configuration task.
[INFO] Configuration XML file loaded: file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/mmm/workspace/project.persistence/target/hibernate3/generated-mappings/hibernate.cfg.xml
12:15:17,484  INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - configuring from url: file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/mmm/workspace/project.persistence/target/hibernate3/generated-mappings/hibernate.cfg.xml
12:15:19,046  INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Reading mappings from resource : package.name/Messages.hbm.xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:hibernate3-maven-plugin:2.2:hbm2java (hbm2java) on project project.persistence: Execution hbm2java of goal org.codehaus.mojo:hibernate3-maven-plugin:2.2:hbm2java failed: resource: package/name/Messages.hbm.xml not found
```

How do I deal with that? Of course I could add:

```
<outputDirectory>src/main/resources/package/name</outputDirectory>
```

to the `hbm2hbmxml` goal, but I think this is not the best approach, or is it? Is there a way to keep **all** the generated code and resources away from the `src/` folder?

I assume, the goal of this approach is not to generate any sources into my src/main/java or /resources folder, but to keep the generated code in the target folder. As I generally agree with this point of view, I'd like to continue with that eventually executing `hbm2dao` and packaging the project to be used as a generated persistence layer component from the business layer. Is this also what you meant?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> how can I configure hbm2cfgxml so that hibernate.cfg.xml looks like below (...)

I have a project that is using `hbm2cfgxml` and the `<mapping resource="..."/>` entries do reflect the packagename in the path to the `hbm.xml`. So there is clearly something wrong on your side. Here are a few remarks:

- I would bind `hbm2cfgxml` on the `generate-resources` phase, you're not generating sources
- I wouldn't generate the file in `src/main/resources` but in `target/classses` (why do you put generated stuff in the source tree, you want a `clean` to clean it).
- There is a typo, it's `configurationfile`, not `configurationFile` but...
- Why the hell do you have a `<configurationfile>` in the configuration of `hbm2cfgxml`? You want to generate it here... I would remove it.

**Update:** You should put the informations required to connect to the database in `src/main/resources/database.properties` (that's the default value of the [`propertyfile`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/maven-hibernate3/hibernate3-maven-plugin/componentproperties.html) property), not in `src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml` (remove that file). Below a sample `database.properties`:

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:derby://localhost:1527//home/pascal/Projects/derbyDBs/EMPLDB
hibernate.connection.username=APP
hibernate.connection.password=APP
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect
```

And as I said, remove the `src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml` file, you want to generate it.

> is there a way to tell maven to copy resources to the target folder before executing hbm2java? (...)

The [`hbm2java`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/maven-hibernate3/hibernate3-maven-plugin/hbm2java-mojo.html) goal *Invokes the execution of the lifecycle phase process-resources  prior to executing itself* (from the documentation). So that's the default behavior and occurs with `hibernate3:hbm2java` or `generate-sources` **if** `hbm2java` is bound to it.

Comment: Thanks for your remarks Pascal. I moved the execution to generate-resources, corrected the typo.
  1. How should I configure the user and password for hibernate-tools if not by hibernate.cfg.xml (or hibernate.properties)? The idea here is, hibernate.cfg.xml is being read, and updated if any changes in the data model have been made. Is there any more-optimal approach? All other options force me to maintain the same configuration in 2 separate files with different syntax.

Regarding my second question, also thanks for your answer. The main question regarding the path/to/mappings is still open.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I fixed my problem by forcing maven to put the `hbm.xml` files into the */target/classes/package/name* folder, so at the end my pom looks like this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>hbm2cfgxml</id>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>hbm2cfgxml</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <inherited>false</inherited>
                    <configuration>
                        <components>
                            <component>
                                <name>hbm2cfgxml</name>
                                <implementation>jdbcconfiguration</implementation>
                            </component>
                        </components>
                        <componentProperties>
                            <packagename>package.name</packagename>
                        </componentProperties>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>hbm2hbmxml</id>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>hbm2hbmxml</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <inherited>false</inherited>
                    <configuration>
                        <components>
                            <component>
                                <name>hbm2hbmxml</name>
                                <outputDirectory>target/classes</outputDirectory>
                            </component>
                        </components>
                        <componentProperties>
                            <packagename>package.name</packagename>
                        </componentProperties>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>hbm2java</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>hbm2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <inherited>false</inherited>
                    <configuration>
                        <components>
                            <component>
                                <name>hbm2java</name>
                                <implementation>configuration</implementation>
                            </component>
                        </components>
                        <componentProperties>
                            <packagename>package.name</packagename>
                            <configurationfile>target/hibernate3/generated-mappings/hibernate.cfg.xml</configurationfile>
                        </componentProperties>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>hbm2dao</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>hbm2dao</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <inherited>false</inherited>
                    <configuration>
                        <components>
                            <component>
                                <name>hbm2dao</name>
                                <implementation>configuration</implementation>
                            </component>
                        </components>
                        <componentProperties>
                            <packagename>package.name</packagename>
                            <configurationfile>target/hibernate3/generated-mappings/hibernate.cfg.xml</configurationfile>
                        </componentProperties>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                    <version>8.4-701.jdbc3</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And it works ok. As fas as I could see in other posts, in some early build phases those `hbm.xml` files should be copied from *target/hibernate3/generated-mappings* (where they are generated by default) to *target/classes/package/name* (where hibernate-tools looks for them), but in my case they aren't (which indicates I'm doing something wrong). So if there is anyone out there knowing what it might be I'm doing wrong, please tell me. Otherwise It'll have to suffice.

There is one thing that isn't working: the package names aren't used in the generated POJOs and DAOs: but I created another thread for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848567/how-to-configure-hbm2java-and-hbm2dao-to-add-packagename-to-generated-classes).

**Update:** ok, now I finally got it. The problem with missing package names was in the `hbm2hbmxml` goal's configuration. I missed the *componentProperties* with *packagename* there, so the generated `hbm.xml` missed the fully classified class names. I updated the above pom, now it works fine. The issue regarding explicit copying the `hbm.xml` files to the *target/classes* folder is still the case, though.

Answer (score 1):

For an example about how to use Hibernate tools with maven, without using hibernate3-maven-plugin check [this post](http://eugencovaci.blogspot.ro/2016/02/hibernate-tools-reverse-engineering.html). The idea is to run Hibernate tools Ant task with Maven. This approach gives you the full control over the process.