# How to configure hbm2java and hbm2dao to add packagename to generated classes

Tags: hibernate, maven-2, hibernate-tools, hbm2java

I'm trying to configure `hbm2java` with maven to generate POJO classes and DAO objects. One of the issues I'm dealing with is package names aren't generated. I'm using the following pom for that:

```
<execution>
    <id>hbm2java</id>
    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>hbm2java</goal>
    </goals>
    <inherited>false</inherited>
    <configuration>
        <components>
            <component>
                <name>hbm2java</name>
                <implementation>configuration</implementation>
            </component>
        </components>
        <componentProperties>
            <packagename>package.name</packagename>
            <configurationfile>target/hibernate3/generated-mappings/hibernate.cfg.xml</configurationfile>
        </componentProperties>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

Yet the generated code begins with the following:

```
// default package
// Generated 2010-05-17 13:11:51 by Hibernate Tools 3.2.2.GA

/**
 * Messages generated by hbm2java
 */
public class Messages  implements java.io.Serializable {
```

Is there a way to force maven to generate the *package* part as defined in *packagename*?

**Update:**

Here is my hibernate.cfg.xml, also automatically generated by hibernate-tools (hbm2cfgxml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <mapping resource="package/name/Messages.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: What does your hibernate.cfg.xml file look like.  Is it possible that the file is overriding the setting?  Also, note that the config file you have specified is misspelled, hibernane.cfg.xml.  I'm not sure if thats intentional or not.

Comment: The misspelling arised while copy-pasting and formatting the code for StackOverflow - but thanks. I added my hibernate.cfg.xml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case, here is a working configuration of the hibernate3-maven-plugin for a bottom-up approach:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>generate-xml-files</id>
        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>hbm2hbmxml</goal>
          <goal>hbm2cfgxml</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>generate-entities</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>hbm2java</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <components>
        <component>
          <name>hbm2hbmxml</name>
          <implementation>jdbcconfiguration</implementation>
          <outputDirectory>target/classes</outputDirectory>
        </component>
        <component>
          <name>hbm2cfgxml</name>
          <implementation>jdbcconfiguration</implementation>
          <outputDirectory>target/classes</outputDirectory>
        </component>
        <component>
          <name>hbm2java</name>
          <implementation>configuration</implementation>
          <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/hibernate3</outputDirectory>
        </component>
      </components>
      <componentProperties>
        <propertyfile>src/main/resources/database.properties</propertyfile>
        <jdk5>true</jdk5>
        <ejb3>false</ejb3>
        <packagename>com.mycompany.myapp</packagename>
        <format>true</format>
        <haltonerror>true</haltonerror>
      </componentProperties>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
        <version>10.5.3.0_1</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugin>
```

And here is the content of my `src/main/database.properties` file:

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:derby:./derbyDBs/EMPLDB
hibernate.connection.username=APP
hibernate.connection.password=APP
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect

#workaround for http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HBX-1145
hibernate.connection.autocommit=true
```

This setup:

1. Generates `*.hbm.xml` in `target/classes` (with the package) during `generate-resources`.
2. Generates a `hibernate.cfg.xml` in `target/classes` with entries for the mapping files.
3. Generates entities from the mappings in `target/generated-sources/hibernate3` (I recommend following the `target/generated-sources/<tool>` convention for generated sources so that they will get auto-detected by IDEs).

Here is a the result of `clean compile` against a sample database with two tables:

```
$ mvn clean compile
...
$ tree target/
target/
├── classes
│   ├── com
│   │   └── mycompany
│   │       └── myapp
│   │           ├── Department.class
│   │           ├── Department.hbm.xml
│   │           ├── Employee.class
│   │           └── Employee.hbm.xml
│   ├── database.properties
│   └── hibernate.cfg.xml
└── generated-sources
    └── hibernate3
        └── com
            └── mycompany
                └── myapp
                    ├── Department.java
                    └── Employee.java
```

Comment: Nice, simpler than mine :). Do you have a clue why the hbm.xml files don't get copied automatically to target/classes from generated-sources/hibernate3/generated-mappings before generate-sources goal gets executed? I see you also force maven to put those files directly in the target/classes folder. Isn't there a way to configure that somehow?

Comment: @mmm I don't know why they aren't (the plugin should *add* this directory as resource directory to the pom). It should be possible to use the Build Helper plugin (see the [Usage](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html) page) for that though. But this would be more verbose and I don't see real benefits. So, since the solution I'm using just works, I never tried to do it another way.

Comment: Even though i set the phase as generate-resources this goal never gets executed for. is there any wrong i am doing?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. I put the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843949/how-to-configure-hibernate-tools-with-maven-to-generate-hibernate-cfg-xml-hbm).