# How to perform database scaffolding in Spring 2.7 using Maven and JDK 8?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, oracle-sqldeveloper, scaffolding

I'm working on a Spring 2.7 project using Maven and JDK 8, and I need to perform database scaffolding for an Oracle database. I have set up the required dependencies, but I'm unsure about the steps to scaffold the database in Spring 2.7.

I've added the necessary dependencies for Spring, but I'm not sure how to proceed with the database scaffolding process. I expected to automatically generate entities and data access code like in .NET scaffolding. However, I'm unsure about the correct approach for Spring 2.7. I'm seeking guidance or code examples on how to achieve this in my project. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848567/how-to-configure-hbm2java-and-hbm2dao-to-add-packagename-to-generated-classes

Answer (score 0):

You could use a lightweight code generator to scaffold your project, for example Telosys (https://www.telosys.org/), it was designed for this.
In your case, you can do the following:

1. create the Telosys model (all the entities and relationship) from your  database (automatic)
2. use (or adapt) templates to generate differents layers of your project : REST controllers, domain classes, persistence, unit tests, etc
   Thanks to templates customization you can generate exactly the code you want